# How to set event handler in React sub-component

Tags: onclick, components, handler, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting menu items connected to an event handler. Here's a mock of the UI showing state changes over time. It's a dropdown menu (via Bootstrap), with the root menu item showing the current selection:

```
[ANN]<click  ...  [ANN]             ...    [BOB]<click  ...  [BOB]  
                    [Ann]                                      [Ann]
                    [Bob]<click + ajax                         [Bob]
                    [Cal]                                      [Cal]
```

The end goal is to change the page content asynchronously based on the user's selection. Clicking on Bob should trigger the `handleClick`, but it's not.

As a side note, I'm not terribly happy with the way componentDidMount calls `this.handleClick();`, but it works for now as a way to get initial menu content from the server.

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var CurrentSelection = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.handleClick();
  },

  handleClick: function(event) {
    alert('clicked');
    // Ajax details ommitted since we never get here via onClick
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {title: "Loading items...", items: []};
  },
  render: function() {
    var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (item) {
      return <li key={item}><a href='#' onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</a></li>;
    });

    return <ul className='nav'>
      <li className='dropdown'>
        <a href='#' className='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>{this.state.title}</a>
        <ul className='dropdown-menu'>{itemNodes}</ul>
      </li>
    </ul>;
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  React.renderComponent(
    CurrentSelection(),
    document.getElementById('item-selection')
  );
});
```

I'm almost positive that my hazy understanding of javascript scoping is to blame, but everything I've tried so far has failed (including trying to pass the handler down through props).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the item nodes using an anonymous function, and inside that `this` means the `window`. The fix is to add `.bind(this)` to the anonymous function.

```
var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (item) {
  return <li key={item}><a href='#' onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</a></li>;
}.bind(this));
```

Or create a copy of `this` and use that instead:

```
var _this = this, itemNodes = this.state.items.map(function (item) {
  return <li key={item}><a href='#' onClick={_this.handleClick}>{item}</a></li>;
})
```

Comment: You can also pass `map` a second argument of `this` which it'll use as the context within which to execute the mapping function.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much! I ended up factoring out the function parameter to `map` to make it more readable with `this` as the second param: `var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(this.itemNode, this);`

Comment: @clozach- If this answers your question, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: @clozach if you extracted into a function, you no longer need the context obj for map - all methods on a component are autobound to the current instance anyway. So this will work fine: `var itemNodes = this.state.items.map(this.itemNode)`

Comment: This answer is great and concise and understandable to me Vs much documentation that seems to be written for people who already know...TY

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand the specification of the task for "Anna", "Bob", "Cal, the solution can be the following (based on a react component and ES6):

[Basic live demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jzolk2l4z5)

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

export default class CurrentSelection extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    }
    this.list = ["Anna", "Bob", "Cal"]
  }

  listLi = list => {
    return list.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <a
          name={item}
          href="#"
          onClick={e => this.onEvent(e, index)}
        >
          {item}
        </a>
      </li>
    ))
  }

  onEvent = (e, index) => {
    console.info("CurrentSelection->onEvent()", { [e.target.name]: index })
    this.setState({ index })
  }

  getCurrentSelection = () => {
    const { index } = this.state
    return this.list[index]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.listLi(this.list)}</ul>
        <div>{this.getCurrentSelection()}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```